# Given the value of a finite weighted sum of quadratic numbers can we recalculate the sum if the weights are shifted?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Please consider a situation where we have a set of weights $a_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, which are all unknown except $a_1$ and we also know the sum $A = \sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}$.

We have been provided with

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n{i^2 a_i}$$

We need to find the following sum:

$$
Y = \sum_{i=1}^n{(i+1)^2 a_i}
$$

We are therefore looking to “shift” the weights/coefficients of the quadratic numbers by one index.

As a trivial example, if $n=2$ then we can just work out $a_2$ from $X$ and $a_1$:

$$\begin{aligned}
X &= a_1 + 4 a_2 \\
a_2 &= \frac{1}{4}(X-a_1) \\
Y &= \sum_{i=1}^2{(i+1)^2 a_i} \\
&= 4a_1+9a_2 \\
&= 4a_1 + \frac{9}{4}(X-a_1)
\end{aligned}$$

But I am looking to be able to define $Y$ in terms of $X$ (and/or $A$ and $a_1$) more generally ($n>2$).

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Y=\sum_1^n (i+1)^2 a_i = \sum_1^n i^2 a_i+2\sum_1^n i a_i+\sum_1^n a_i = X+2\sum_1^n i a_i+A$$

No it is not possible in general. There are 2 independent equations - ie for $X, A$. There are $n-1$ unknowns $a_2..a_n$. You can only solve if there are 2 unknowns - ie $a_2, a_3$.

(Incidentally in your example you are given $A=a_1+a_2$ as well as $a_1$ therefore you can deduce $a_2=A-a_1$ immediately.)